# Haskell, how to initialize type list, where you define the contents, and also add some initial contents

Tags: list, haskell, types, initialization

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm just a bit confused on what syntax to use.

Say I have a type list defined as the following:

> type myList = [(String, Int)]

But say I want to initialize some contents in the list for example ("test", 2), would that be possible to do on the same line that I initialized myList?

One thing I tried was just initializing it like how you'd normally do so with an ordinary list:

type myList = [(String, Int)] = [("test", 2)]

but this gave me a parse on =, but I don't know any other way to do it.

Comment: `myList`, as you've written it is a _type_, and not a _value._

Answer (score 4):

Define variables of a type on an extra line:

```hs
type MyList = [(String, Int)]

myList :: MyList -- optional type declaration
myList = [("test", 2)]
```

Comment: myList is not a variable, there are none in Haskell. It’s a function.